# datatable 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I use a DataTable in laravel. My url path is correct.

I am receiving a 404 error.

Please give solution

```
http://localhost:8000/upload/gambar/paket/'+name+' 404 (Not Found)
 columns: [
  { name: 'paket_wisata.gambar',
          render: function(name, type, row) {          
              return '<img src="{{asset("upload/gambar/paket/'+name+'")}}" />';
          }       
   }    
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing here a client side with server side which is impossible like that:

```
return '<img src="{{asset("upload/gambar/paket/'+name+'")}}" />';
```

you can solve it by:

```
render: function(name, type, row) {
    var url = '{{asset("upload/gambar/paket/:node")}}';
    url = url.replace(':node', name);
    return '<img src="'+url+'" />';
}
```